# Ajax POST returns 500; Chrome Postman works fine

Tags: jquery, ajax, postman

So I am trying to "translate" this request into jQuery's ajax:

[image]

and the code:

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://domain.com/api/useprofile',
                data: {
                   "first_name": "Joe",
                   "last_name": "Doe",
                   "bio": "Lorem Ipsum"
                },
                headers: {
                   "X-CSRFToken": $rootScope.csrftoken
                },
                success: function(msg){
                    alert(JSON.stringify(msg));
                },
                error: function(msg,textStatus){
                    alert(JSON.stringify(msg.status));
                }
            });
```

I tried different types of contentType and dataType but none of them worked (error 500) while Postman successfully sends data and receives 201 response code

**EDIT. Solved the issue. Apparently I had JSON.stringify the data field.**

Comment: Could it be because you're missing the "bio" form data in your AJAX request? Do you have access to the server side logs? A status of 500 indicates that the request hit the server, but the server could not process the request for some reason.

Comment: Thank you for your response. In fact I do send the bio field it was wrong copy-paste. I also get a feeling that the issue is related to the "data" field. If I remove it completely from Postman it returns the same error, 500.

Comment: 500 is a pretty generic error. So if you remove the necessary form data, then it's possible the server can't handle the request because the request is not properly formed.

Comment: Just edited the original post. Thank you for actually pointing out at "data" in your first reply.